# Errors runing phpmyadmin "File Not Found"

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

I have a problem when trying to run phpmyadmin on my server. My server is Ubuntu20.04 with nginx and mysql and php7.4. So I installed it and configured from ssh and after:
Error log from nginx:

```
2023/01/17 11:05:20 [error] 1154853#1154853: *209 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.127.142.237, server: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "XX.XX.XX.XX"
```

my default.conf server block for nginx is:

```
access_log /usr/share/nginx/html/click_access_log;
   error_log /usr/share/nginx/html/click_error_log;

   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.php index.htm index.html;

       location / {
           index   index.html index.htm index.php;
         }

  location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
    index  index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    gzip off;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

}
```

When I try to access phpmyadmin after from http://IP/phpmyadmin/ i get a text with "File Not Found"

Can you pease help? I'm sure something is wrong with my nginx server config.
Thank you

Comment: Try replacing the `fastcgi_param` statement with: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;`

Comment: @RichardSmith I did, now i have an error in nginx: FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\mb_strpos() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:253

Comment: That appears to be an unrelated error that implies that either PHP or phpmyadmin is not installed correctly.